# Creating an array of objects, from multiple buttons in IB, XCode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, arrays

I want to have three sets of 10 buttons for an iOS app. I want to show/hide each set (reveal one set at a time). I am planning to use tags to do this.

As it is I have a property for each button (ex: btn01, btn02, etc), so I have 30 properties. I add that to an array, and then use the following code to hide buttons with one tag or the other.

My question is, is there a more efficient way to create the array of objects, rather than setting up 30 properties (one for each button). It's fine, just wonder if there is a cleaner way, using a loop to gather each button from IB somehow. Can't think of it.

```
    if (tagState == 1) {
        tagState = 2;
    }else {
        tagState = 1;
    }

    for (btn in myArray) {
        NSLog(@"%@",btn);
        if (tagState == 1) {
            if (btn.tag == 1) {
                [btn setHidden:YES];
            }
            if (btn.tag == 2) {
                [btn setHidden:NO];
            }

        } else if (tagState == 2) {
            if (btn.tag == 1) {
                [btn setHidden:NO];
            }
            if (btn.tag == 2) {
                [btn setHidden:YES];
            }

        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add each set of buttons to a different UIView and then simply hide/show each view as needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the view hierarchy very effectively here: put each group of buttons into its own `UIView`, connect only the three `UIView`s to outlets, and hide/show *them*. Note that this only works if you don't also need to access the individual buttons for some other reason.

Comment: I think this is what I am going to do. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IBOutletCollection`, it is an `NSArray` of outlets.

To e.g. hide all outlets from a collection, you can use

```
[outlets setValue:@YES forKey:@"hidden"]
```

or

```
[outlets setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"hidden"]
```

when using LLVM < 4.0